# Кастомный вид для групп ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Подскажите пожалуйста.. сделала свою разметку для заголовков групп в `ExpandableListView`. В адаптере написала следующее:

```
public class ExpListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    DBHeler dbHeler;
    private int layout;

    public ExpListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        this.layout = childLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
      view.setTag(viewHolder);
      return view;
   }

   @Override
   protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded) {
      super.bindGroupView(view, context, cursor, isExpanded);

      ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
      String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME));
      holder.txtCategory.setText(category);
   }


}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Process: test.myapp, PID: 6572
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>   at test.myapp.ExpListAdapter.bindGroupView(ExpListAdapter.java:82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка вызвана тем, что для кастомного вида групп вы указываете не ту разметку:

```
public class ExpListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    DBHeler dbHeler;
    private int layoutChild;
    ptivate int layoutGroup;

    public ExpListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        dbHeler = new DBHeler(context);
        layoutChild = childLayout;
        layoutGroup = groupLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutGroup, parent, false); // разметка групп
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View view = inflater.inflate(layoutChild, parent, false); // разметка вложенных
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
      view.setTag(viewHolder);
      return view;
    }
}
```

Для изменения вида индикатора раскрытия групп нужно нарисовать два вида этого индикатора: закрытый и раскрытый, затем написать селектор, назовем его indicator.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/group_indicator_expanded" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/group_indicator" />
</selector>
```

файл помещаем в папку *res/drawable*

Теперь в разметке вашего `ExpandableListView` указываем этот индикатор:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/indicator" >
</ExpandableListView
```

>

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо. Последний маленький вопросик. Этот индикатор у меня растягивается на всю высоту группы, можно  ли сделать чтобы он не растягивался, а был такого же размера как и был?

Comment: @Вероника делаете индикатор формата 9-patch. Указываете области растяжения - края вашего индикатора, где нет изображения, чтобы растягивалось пустое пространство.

Comment: @Вероника чтобы развернуть первую группу `expdListView.expandGroup(0);`

Comment: создала вопрос.