# Как раскрыть первую группу в ExpandableListView программно

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Как раскрыть первую группу в `ExpandableListView` программно?

```
expList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expList);
        expList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expList.expandGroup(0);
```

в итоге не раскрывает первую группу когда приложение запускается, использую кастомный адаптер из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628380/177345)

Comment: У вас в разметке для группы есть кликабельные виджеты? кнопки, чекбоксы, поля ввода и тп.?

Comment: Нет, только ImageView и TextView

Comment: А при нажатии пальцем раскрывается? я не могу у себя воспроизвести проблему

Comment: да, раскрывается. На эмуляторе проверяла я.

Answer (score 1):

Я поставил вызов `expand()` в `onResume`, и у меня получилось.